How to escape symbols inside runuser command?
I want to get list of PostgreSQL databases.
PostgreSQL works by postgres user, so I need to use runuser.
While I'm execute
runuser -l postgres -c 'psql -tc "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname <> ALL ('{template0,template1,postgres}');"'

I get
ERROR:  column "template0" does not exist
LINE 1: ...CT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname <> ALL (template0)...

So if I execute runuser command while logging in as postgres by su it works.

See Escaping single quotes inside a single quoted sub-command, itself inside a double quoted command

If you can do without the -l option, the easiest solution is to take advantage of the alternate syntax available with the runuser command:
runuser -u postgres -- psql -tc \
  "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname <> ALL ('{template0,template1,postgres}');"

Et voila, we have eliminated one level of quoting.

Hm. I got another problem - could not change directory to "/root" while list of databases have only user databases.
So I just use now
runuser -l postgres -c "psql -tc 'SELECT datname FROM pg_database;'" | grep -v "template0$\|template1$\|postgres$\|^$"
It doesn't look good, but it works. (but I want to know how to set directory AND where is from -u parameter cause I cannot find it in the psql --help output)

And what is -- while we're using runuser?
I know that it possibly is redirection, but.. it's a little confusing.

That isn't specific to runuser, nor does it have anything to do with redirection. -- is the standard way of declaring that all of the following argument are non-option arguments.
